# Discount Problem

Tags: percentages

A shopkeeper allows a discount of 10% on the marked price. How much above the cost price must he mark his goods to gain 8%?

I assume cost price to be P. So the shopkeeper must get 1.08P to make a profit of 8%. He allows a discount of 10%. I am told that 90% of marked price is 1.08P because the shopkeeper offers a discount of 10%. Can somebody please explain why 90% of marked price is 1.08P?

Comment: marked up price $ \times (1 - 0.01) = 1.08 \, \times \,$ actual cost.

Comment: LHS is the final price the customer pays. RHS is the the price the shopkeeper should finally get to make $8\%$ profit (over cost). Both are equal as per the question.

Answer (score 1):

To flesh out Math Lover's brief description:

Let $M$ be the marked price of the prpoduct and $P$ be the cost price.
As you've noted, the shopkeeper *wants to get* at least $1.08\cdot P$ from the sale.

Because of the $10\%$ discount, the amount the shopkeeper *will get* from the sale is $0.9\cdot M$.

So for the shopkeeper to get the amount they want, these two need to be equal:
$$0.9\cdot M = 1.08 \cdot P$$
Solving for $M$,
$$M = \dfrac{1.08}{0.9}P$$